# Replace script tag that has a dynamic version number which keeps changing

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to remove or replace this string in an HTML file using javascript.

```
'<script src="../assets/js/somejs.js?1.0.953"></script>'
```

Trouble is, the version number "1.0.953" keeps changing so I can't use a simple string.replace

Comment: Should that be done in client-side js or server-side js?

Comment: you can remove all characters after the ? symbol

Comment: Its part of my build system using node. Yes I would like all the characters from ? to the closing script tag removed along with the initial replacement string.

Comment: try looking for some build config to disable echoing the version number rather then patching the output

Comment: What is your build system?

Comment: I am using a 3rd party software package to develop a website. The software writes out the HTML so i can only manipulate it post export. I am building a custom build system (node / javascript) to massage this HTML. Im stuck on removing or replacing this line though as the 3rd party software generates it.

Comment: And more importantly, do you understand why the version is added in the first place? What is the reason you want to remove it?

Comment: The software I am using is brilliant as a web design tool. However, it sucks at producing good HTML as the SEO is terrible. My build system basically keeps all the good parts and removes the stuff I don't need. For example, this script mentioned is not needed within my site hence why I want to remove it. the version number is therefore irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is messy but it works...

```
String.prototype.replaceAnyVersionOfScript = function(target, replacement) {

    // 1. Build the string we need to replace (target + xxx + ></script>)
    var targetLength = target.length;
    var targetStartPos = this.indexOf(target);
    var dynamicStartPos = targetStartPos + targetLength;
    var dynamicEndPos = this.indexOf('></script>', dynamicStartPos) + 10;
    var dynamicString = this.substring(dynamicStartPos, dynamicEndPos);
    var dymamicStringToReplace = target + dynamicString;

    // 2. Now we know what we are looking for. We can replace it.         
    return this.replace(dymamicStringToReplace, replacement);

};

shellHTML = shellHTML.replaceAnyVersionOfScript('<script src="./assets/js/CloudZoom.js', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using the following Regex:

```
\?.*?\"
```

Or, more specifically

```
(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)
```

For matching the version number.

Utilizing the regex, you can replace the version number with a blank value.